# Adding styles to bootstrap classes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-lg-offset-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-10">
```

I would like to add a custom style (padding: 20px for example) which will get applied **only when col-sm-4 is applied (only to small layout)**. I tried adding it right to the .col-sm-4 class, but it affected all layouts. Any example how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using bootstraps default breakpoint widths:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:767px)
{
   .col-sm-4{padding:20px;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have my bootstrap set up so that I use less, along with a custom less file that has access to the variables in bootstrap.  I would do this:

```
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
  .custom-class {
       padding:20px;
  }
}
```

Otherwise, you can do this:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .custom-class {
       padding:20px;
  }
}
```

Then you can add custom-class to your list of classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries in CSS to apply styles to a certain id or class.

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {

       #myId{padding:20px;} 

       .myClass{padding:20px;;}

       .col-xs-4{padding:20px;;}
     }
```

The above will apply the 20px padding to example id's / classes as long as the screen width does not exceed 767px.

Official documentation about when certain classes break can be found here : 
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries

the col-xs- class requires the screen to be <768 pixels.